# Pass data from mainwindow > tabitem > scroller > frame > content

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I asked this question already but now I have a better understanding of what I'm trying to do. I have a WPF application with a `mainwindow` class. From there, `tabitems` can be created. For example, I have an `account` tab. My problem is that I want to use the `account.xaml` for the "edit account' *and* the "add account" button. How can I tell `account.xaml.vb` whether it is in edit mode or add mode? Similarly - how do I tell `account.vb` which account it is editing from a dialogue box that I show when "edit account" is clicked?

Here is the tab being created in `mainwindow.xaml.vb`

```
    Private Sub btn_AddAccount_Click(sender As Object, e As   
    RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn_AddAccount.Click

    Dim tab_NewAccount As New C1TabItem()
    Dim frame_NewAccount As New Frame()
    Dim scroller_NewAccount As New ScrollViewer()
    Dim str_Name As String = "Add Account"
    Dim str_NavigationLink As String = "PM_AddAccount.xaml"
    Dim account As New PM_AddAccount
    account.mode = 1

    'Add and name new tab
    tab_NewAccount.Header = tabcontrol.Items.Count + 1 & ". " & str_Name
    tab_NewAccount.CanUserClose = True
    tabcontrol.Items.Add(tab_NewAccount)

    'Add frame to the tab and include new page
    With frame_NewAccount
        .NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(str_NavigationLink, UriKind.Relative))
        .HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
        .VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
        .Margin = New Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)
    End With

    With scroller_NewAccount
        .CanContentScroll = vbTrue
        .VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
        .HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
        .Content = frame_NewAccount
    End With

    tab_NewAccount.Content = scroller_NewAccount
    ' Set new tab as active tab
    tabcontrol.SelectedIndex = tabcontrol.Items.IndexOf(TAB)

End Sub
```

Edit:
So I tried giving `Account.xaml.vb` a public property and then setting that in `mainwindow.xaml.vb` However, the value isn't getting set - I realize that the `account` variable in `mainwindow.xaml.vb` isn't connected anything but `frame.content = account` doesnt work either.

```
Class Account

Public Property mode As AccountMode
    Get
        Return mode
    End Get
    Set(value As AccountMode)
        value = mode
    End Set
End Property

Public Enum AccountMode
    None = 0
    Add = 1
    Edit = 2
End Enum

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an enum called `AccountMode`

```
Public Enum AccountMode
    None = 0
    Add = 1
    Edit = 0
End Enum
```

Add a property to `account.xaml.vb` called Mode And set it appropriately as needed.

In regard to how to tell it which account it is editing, that question is vague. Typically you would be binding your control to a data source and that data source will have some kind of key or identifier  that makes it unique from all other records. For example, if you are binding your data from a database there would be a Primary Key and/or Identity Field.

Your data would be bound to a model class like this:

```
Public Class Account
    [Key]
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
End Class
```

Likewise, Instead of have a mode in your Account class you could incorporate logic that detects you are adding a new Account if the Account.Id = 0. Otherwise if Account.Id>0 then you are editing an existing account.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Where would I declare the enum?

Comment: You can declare it anywhere, most commonly in its own class file.